# Why am I getting a "use of undeclared identifier error"?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

The error line is:

```
test = Grid::createGrid("empty.png");
```

the source file declaring the class is:

```
Grid* Grid::createGrid(std::string texture)
{
    Grid* pGrid = new Grid();
    pGrid->initWithFile(texture);
    pGrid->autorelease();
    Size size = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    int scale = pGrid->getContentSize().height/((size.height-size.height*0.1)/10);
    pGrid->setScale(scale, scale);

    return pGrid;
}
```

I am sure this should work as I have done the exact same code for another program also in xcode...

Comment: Looks like `test` is not declared?

Comment: toss an `auto` in front of `test =` or `Grid*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a declaration for the test, like:

```
Grid* test;
```

Or:

```
Grid* test = Grid::createGrid("empty.png");
```

Or:

```
@property Grid* test;
```